# Does Github rate limit apply globally per IP address?

Tags: github, github-api

From the Github doc:

> For requests using Basic Authentication or OAuth, you can make up to 5,000 requests per hour.

Is 5000 reqs/hour global or per IP address?

Comment: @TheNickmaster21 Umm.. I'm trying to write a client..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per client. Before you write your own client though I would check out this list of [wrappers](http://developer.github.com/v3/libraries/).